# Executing multiple MySQL SELECT queries python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I need to execute multiple MySQL select queries in Python. I am thinking of doing it in this way:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host = HOSTNAME, user = USERNAME, passwd = PASSWORD, db = DATABASE, port=PORT)
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    query_table0 = 'SELECT %s FROM %s'%(COLUMN.get(TABLES[0]),TABLES[0])
    query_table1 = 'SELECT %s FROM %s'%(COLUMN.get(TABLES[1]),TABLES[1])
    query_table2 = 'SELECT %s FROM %s'%(COLUMN.get(TABLES[2]),TABLES[2])
    cursor.execute(query_table0)
    result_table0 = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute(query_table1)
    result_table1 = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute(query_table2)
    result_table2 = cursor.fetchall()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Is there any more optimised way of executing multiple SQL statements in Python?

Comment: There are neater ways, one of them is using an object relational manager like Djangos orm or sqlalchemy. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need it for analytics purposes, so finally will be converting in JSON to be dumped to mongoDB. I am not going to use it in any web applications, so need no frameworks. That's why looking for a simple solution that can reduce code in my program.

Comment: You can use the executemany method for that but it won't optimize the query any, just clean up your code a bit. ORMs will optimize a query (or should at least), but using raw SQL is just that, the raw sql.